# Improve performance for query that includes many conditions with "or" operator

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-design

I have table that having three columns (Region, State, City)

```
CREATE TABLE ads (
    Region varchar(100),
    State varchar(100),
    City varchar(100),
    ....
);
```

And I want to execute the following query

```
SELECT * FROM ads
WHERE region=? OR state=? OR city=?
```

What is the best index I can use to decrease search time ?

I tried to use multi-column index

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON ads (region, state, city);
```

But seems it doesn't work

Comment: Please take some time to peruse the many, MANY questions here on query optimization. You will note that the ones which are upvoted and answered include *full* table schemas and explain plans.

Comment: A multi-column index is the exact opposite of what you would need.

Comment: MySQL generally has trouble optimizing `OR` queries. It's usually better to do multiple queries and combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: A mutli-column index like that would only help you with "AND" conditions, and would only help as long as the columns earlier in the index are involved. I.E. `(region, state, city)` will only help with `state` if `region` is an ANDed condition, and will only help with `city` if the other two are parts of ANDed conditions. As Barmar state, MySQL does not take advantage of indexes well with OR; and if it did, it would be more likely to take advantage of separate single-column indexes that would help with the UNION also mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That index will not help.  It would help a lot if the `WHERE` used `ANDs` instead of `ORs`.

Plan A:  `FULLTEXT(region, state, city)` and `WHERE MATCH(region, state, city) AGAINST('+?' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`.  But there some caveats with `FULLTEXT`, so you may find this less than perfect, in spite of being very fast.

Plan B:  Turn `OR` into `UNION`: [*discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#or)

Plan C:  Put the three columns into one and use `WHERE location LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')`.  This will not help, since a full can is still needed.

Plan D:  Change the UI and/or the user expectations.